# Creating classes in C# from Informix tables

Tags: c#, informix

I know that there is POCO Generator but that's for SQL Server and I need it for an Informix database. 
Can you point me to any alternative?

BTW I am using an Informix data server driver in C# to connect to an Informix server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [LINQ to DB](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/wiki), which support couples of databases such as `Informix`:

> Supported databases:
>
> - DB2 (LUW, z/OS)
> - Firebird
> - **Informix**
> - Microsoft Access
> - Microsoft Sql Azure
> - Microsoft Sql Server
> - Microsoft SqlCe
> - MySql
> - Oracle
> - PostgreSQL
> - SQLite
> - SAP HANA
> - Sybase ASE

I hope to be helpful for you:)

Comment: I made it to create classes for my tables and views. My next question is how to create classes for the stored procedures and functions?

Comment: There is a solution for doing this : https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/57.
Check it please.